# angular not conencting to mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I am using angular to connect to mongoose db.
I have got a .js file where i have written the code to insert data in db as:

```
'use strict'

test.controller('registrationCtrl', function($scope){
console.log('1');
    $scope.newregister = function(user) {
        console.log('inside registration function 1');
        var user = require(['../server.js']);
        console.log('inside registration function');

        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        console.log('inside mongoose');

        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
        console.log('inside connect');

        var userSchema = {
            username: String,
            firstname:String,
            lastname: String,
            email: String,
            password: String
        }          



    }

});
```

but when i try to run the code , it is giving error as:

```
1
inside registration function 1
inside registration function
Error: Module name "mongoose" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

---

new js which i have just created to test the db function and is working fine.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
console.log('1');
var userSchema = {
    username: String,
    firstname:String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
}
console.log('2');
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
console.log('3');
var newUser = new User({
    username: 'sa',
    firstname:'sa',
    lastname: 'sa',
    email: 'a@a.com',
    password: 'sa'

});

console.dir(newUser);
newUser.save(function(err){
   if(!err) console.log('inserted successfull');
    else
   {
       console.log('failed');
   }

});
```

Comment: interesting, if you take out the angularJS, Does your mongoose work properly?

Comment: if i add the whole code in .js file and run teh js file, it insert the data in db.I am editing my ques to provide the js which i have just created..and is working fine

Comment: @Hatjhie : Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure how to approach it in your way, but if I were you, I might do this in factory. So, everytime you need to call the mangoose, you just need to inject it in any of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

This line should be outside your controller i.e. just below or above `use strict`

Comment: doing this giving error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: Sorry. Also move this line `var user = require(['../server.js']);` above mongoose require line.

Comment: Hi, I have created a new js file which i am referencing in my another js...i have included both on top

Comment: You might need to do this in Angular way. How about if you create a factory for that mangoose? And afterwards, injecting it in your controller?

Comment: I am not very much comfirtable about teh factory, but can i call the whole js file into another js file?

Comment: @rishiag: Hi, I have tried implementing the factory method...Please have a look......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014862/factory-method-giving-error-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is having a backward dependency. Using `require('mongoose')` in the online webpage(html code) won't work. For this either you can use *browserify* or *require.js* to eliminate these dependencies.
They will let you link your `<script>` js file to require.js(generated automatically) and the code will work fine.
Visit http://requirejs.org/ if you didn't understand it. It is clearly explained there.