# Insert data in mongoose using a factory

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, factory

I am trying to insert data in mongoose using angularjs and node js.
For this i have created a factory where i am calling another js file where i have created my database connection.

But when i tried to do this, it is giving me error.

Here is my factory method:

```
'use strict'
test.factory('registrationservice', function($http, $scope){
    console.log('aa');
    $scope.newregister = function(user, $scope) {

        var newUser = new user({
            username: $scope.uName,
            firstname: $scope.fName,
            lastname: $scope.lName,
            email:$scope.mail,
            password: $scope.newpwd

        });

        console.dir(newUser);

        var $promise = $http.post('data/registration.js', newUser);
        $promise.then(function(msg){
            if(msg.data == 'success') console.log('success login')
            else
                console.log('login failed');
        });
    };

});
```

and below is the error i am getting:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20registrationservice
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: how do u use `registrationservice`?

Comment: I am using it in controller

Comment: I have a feeling that you try to pass '$scope' from controller to factory

Comment: no, my controller is like:  test.controller('registrationCtrl', function(registrationservice){
    console.log('1');

});

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject $scope to factory. Services do not have scopes. Only Controllers.

So you have to use something like this.

```
test.factory('registrationservice', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    // if user is another service you have to inject it in factory defenotion function
    // and delete from here.
    facotry.newregister = function(user, $scope) {

        var newUser = new user({
            username: $scope.uName,
            firstname: $scope.fName,
            lastname: $scope.lName,
            email:$scope.mail,
            password: $scope.newpwd

        });

        return $http.post('data/registration.js', newUser);
    }
    return factory;
});
```

And then in your controller.

```
test.controller('registrationCtrl', function($scope, $log, registrationservice){ 
    registrationservice.newregister(user, $scope).success(function(msg){
        $log.info(msg.data);
    })
});
```

Comment: i ahve tried implementing that, but i am getting error as: 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' at  var newUser = new user({

Comment: Where do you have the User-Object defined?

Comment: This is why I commented inside the code. I do not know where you have this object from. How do you define user?

Comment: I also doubt about post request to .js file.

Comment: NOw after look to your another topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015649/db-insert-using-factory-and-angularjs) I understand what is user. And you completely missed the point. You are trying to pos data from Client to server side javascript. You have to create RESTful service with your server side javascript and then send posts to that service.