# db insert using factory and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I have created factory in angular, from where i want to inset data in mongoose db, but i am not sure how to do that.

I have created factory like:

```
test.factory('registrationservice', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    console.log('1');
    factory.newregister = function(user, $scope) {
       var newUser = new user({
            username: $scope.uName,
            firstname: $scope.fName,
            lastname: $scope.lName,
            email:$scope.mail,
            password: $scope.newpwd

        });

       console.log(newUser);
        var user = require(['../server.js']);
        console.log('2');

     //  return $http.post('data/registration.js');


    }
    return factory;
});
```

and i have another js file where i have defined my db connection as:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/userregistration');
console.log('1');
var userSchema = {
    username: String,
    firstname:String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
}
console.log('2');
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
console.log('3');



newUser.save(function(err){
   if(!err) console.log('inserted successfull');
    else
   {
       console.log('failed');
   }

});
```

Any idea, how to achieve this using factory?

Comment: Are you aware that "mongoose" is a serverside (NodeJS) and AngularJS a client side technology? You can't call the mongoose Service/Schema directly from your angular app. Maybe take a look at the MEAN stack - http://mean.io/#!/

Comment: possible duplicate of [factory method giving error in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014862/factory-method-giving-error-in-angular)

Comment: Please do not abuse stackoverflow. Do not create the same question twice.